# Port forwarding through socks5 proxy without ssh

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding, socks

I want to redirect connections to localhost:5353 on my PC to remoteserver:53 (udp).

However, the connection to the remote server is restricted and must be made through a socks5 proxy.

So I have to redirect the connection *through socks5 proxy*.

I have heard that it can be done using ssh.
But I will be using a small server with few resources,
so I think I need a way to do it without using ssh.
(a lightweight, space-saving way)

How is it possible to do this?
(Also, I would like to know the way to do this *using* ssh)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You could [use socat](https://stackpointer.io/network/ssh-port-forwarding-tcp-udp/365/) to tunnel UDP packets through a TCP connection.